# cgi file upload optimization

Tags: perl, curl

I am implementing a RESTful API using Apache and cgi scripting and performance is critical.  I need to transfer data to the cgi script in the most efficient way possible.  This means the least number of temporary files, or RAM buffering.  Ideally I would go from the IP packets into a 1MB RAM buffer once, and then out to my destination.  Searching the web and this blog there is very little information on the efficiency of transfers.

Mod_perl is often mentioned, and I understand the efficiency there, as the perl interpreter is optimized into Apache.  But where can you get detailed information on buffering for POST requests to a cgi script?

Here is a specific question that I have:  If I use curl to POST a form that is just a file upload, then the cgi script does not get any data from STDIN.  I get data from the file just fine, but it is not via STDIN, but via url_param.  I know I am doing a POST, because the $ENV has it as a POST.  So why don't I see STDIN data?

The second question is if anyone knows of a study on performance of different transfer types?

Comment: I don't have exact answers. But using CGI scripts AD 2013 for perfomance critical RESTFul API does not seem practical approach. When your preference is Perl, you could use some micro-framework, like [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer) or [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious), there is lots work already done, to get RESTful services alive. If you still want help with your CGI scripts you could share some example code to work with.

Comment: I did look at Mojolicious and I'll continue to keep that in mind.  I was concerned about adopting an entire framework.  I also work in a secure environment and it is easier to get approval for perl packages than an entire framework.  It is just easier to hide stuff in a framework.  I have worked this further so I'll post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For effiency you could use Apache2::Upload. It is tightly coupled with apache mod_perl and use C libs (xs) to speed up things.

It is not tested, but something like this:

```
use Apache2::Upload;
open(my $out_fh,'>',outfile) or die $!;
binmode($out_fh);

my $req = Apache2::Request->new($r);
my $upload = $req->upload("foo"); 
my $bb = $upload->bb();
my $contents = '';my $length = '2048';my $offset = 0;
while ( $bb->READ($contents, $length, $offset) ){
   $offset += $length+1;
}
print $out_fh $contents;
```

Comment: This is very helpful as I didn't know about this module.  I have one version working with CGI.pm, but once I get that solid I'll try this module and see which one works better.